# How to I get window drop functionality on Mac OS X?

Tags: windows-7, macos, window, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to I get window drop functionality on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/132750/how-to-i-get-window-drop-functionality-on-mac-os-x)

I really like using the drag-n-drop feature on Windows 7. (*Drag a window to the edge of your screen to auto-fill half the screen, drag it to the top to fill the entire screen.*)

Is there an easy way to get this feature on machines running any other OS's? I'm specifically wondering about Mac OSX, but would love to know about a Windows XP solution too...

Comment: Try looking up [AeroSnap](http://www.aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm). IMO, I'm perfectly fine without Aero/AeroSnap eating away at my CPU.

Comment: Thanks, this was mentioned in one of the answers. (the one I posted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cinch](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) does exactly what you need for Mac OS X, and in my testing works quite well. For a keyboard approach, I recommend [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a Mac shortcut to get the half screen auto-fill effect, but the full screen effect is easy: click the green 'gem' an the top left of the title bar.

For those apps that do not follow this protocol [Right Zoom](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30591/right-zoom) gives you control.

Comment: *those apps that do not follow this protocol* -- the "protocol" is to zoom to the *best* user experience, not to zoom to full screen. OS X applications that zoom to full screen are evil on a large screen.

Comment: To each their own. I use Mail.app, Thunderbird, Gyaz Mail, Postbox Express, NetNewsWire, and others full screen on my 23" CD.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for Vista and XP users is Aerosnap, as described in [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14238/add-windows-7s-aerosnap-feature-to-vista-and-xp/) How-To Geek article. It provides screenshots and the following links: [Download AeroSnap for Windows Vista & XP](http://www.aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm) and [Download the .NET Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en).

Works as advertised on my XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

By searching for "aerosnap mac free" I found [this](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/04/19/shiftit-brings-windows-7-aero-snap-to-your-mac/) recommendation for [ShiftIt](http://code.google.com/p/shiftit/) hosted on code.google.com (which says it's no longer in development). It's description sounds like Cinch except it seems to be controlled via the menu bar rather than drag and drop, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[DoublePane](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/doublepane/id409737246?mt=12&ls=1) is another option for Mac too if you prefer using keyboard shortcuts.